# Add method in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am using `ArrayList` to store the values of Quantity entered by user in shopping cart. But while trying to add the quantity to `ArrayList`, the quantity is not being added. Why is quantity not being added?

The code is here:

```
public class Add_Cart1 extends HttpServlet {

    String id, name, cost, stock;
    ArrayList qty = new ArrayList();

        if(id != null)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < qty.size(); j++)
            {
                System.out.println("values......." + req.getParameterValues("qty"));
                System.out.println("qty........." +
                  qty.add(req.getParameterValues("qty")));

            }   
        }
}
```

Comment: Please trim down the code and remove everything that is not necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: He wants to know why his `qty.add(req.getParameterValues("qty"))` is not adding anything in the `qty` ArrayList

Comment: @JigarJoshi:add method is returning boolean value that is causing problem

Comment: I think you should learn to use a debugger so you don't have to ask these questions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `qty.add()` is inside this for loop:

```
          for(j=0;j<qty.size();j++)
```

But `qty.size()` is 0 because you haven't added anything to the list yet. So nothing ever gets added.

Also, the [`add()` method always returns boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)). Are you sure you're not looking for the `get()` method?

Comment: But I am adding qty.add(req.getParameterValues("qty") inside for loop

Comment: @PrasoonMishra but the loop never gets executed, because the ArrayList "qty" is initially of size 0, and `j<qty.size()` (j<0) condition fails, so nothing is ever added.

Comment: @ Jon Lin:ok I got why it is not adding.so I have to check some other condition to add quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Check [ArrayList.size()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size%28%29)

```
    ArrayList<String> qty = new ArrayList<String>();
    qty.add("123");
    System.out.println(qty.size());
    qty.add("1234");
    System.out.println(qty.size());
```

It will output `1`, `2`

Never use member variables in servlets for data that changes with each user since many requests may be executing at the same time.

Declare your `ArrayList` class as (Assuming `qty` is String)

```
ArrayList<String> qty = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Answer (score 0):

qty.size() will be 0 initially, so it will not enter the loop.